# Java Specialized IDE: Project files vs project zip/jar

Tags: java, file, jar, project

I'm creating a specialized IDE in Java and I need to store and use resources associated with the current project being worked on. Should I store my whole project as one file (an archive), or as a system of files? I would prefer to use an archive (duh, one file.), but I'm unfamiliar with the APIs, and I'm not sure how slow that might be. Would it be terribly slower to read images and various other resources from an archive rather that the raw file system?

For example:

1. User clicks on an image in a jtree
2. Image is loaded *from the file* system to an editor

vs

1. ...
2. Image is loaded *from a jar* to an editor

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'creating a specialized IDE'? are you creating program like Netbeans/Eclipse, or program to edit pictures?
I don't think this is good place to ask about such things, but i would recommend using first option, which is (i think) faster in develop (i'm guessing it is study project and deadline approaches)

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant by faster... I meant bitwise, not timewise. It's not a study project. It's a private project for my company, which is why I've used the term "Specialized IDE". You're not supposed to know what it does; it's not salient to the question. ;)

Comment: Ok, that's explains a lot. I suggest to look at existing programs, that does similar stuff. If it is more like Netbeans/Eclipse (meaning project is made from many objects of many types) then i would use a file system. If it is more like graphical project like Photoshop/Gimp, i would use a single file strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user is likely to be saving their individual project files, then using a filesystem rather than an archive will be a lot faster since the whole archive doesn't need to be written, only the changed files.

If possible you should only read the files once at the time the project is loaded into the editor, and after that have it all in memory. This is a lot faster than reading from the filesystem all the time.

So in summary, it's not the *reading* but the *writing* that would be the bottleneck with an archive.

On the other hand it also depends on how much data we are talking about.